# Unable to perform auto focus with Camera

Tags: android, xamarin, camera

I'm developing an application for android with Xamarin. I have to capture some QR code with the phone. When user click on screen, the Camera haves to perform an auto focus.

There is my code :

```
public class MainActivity
{
    TextureView _textureView;
    Camera _camera;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        _camera = Camera.Open();

        _textureView = FindViewById<TextureView>(Resource.Id.previewView);
        _textureView.SurfaceTextureListener = this;
        _textureView.Click += new EventHandler(clickFocus);
    }

    private void clickFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _camera.AutoFocus(this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

On other class :

```
private void _mainactivity_onFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool focus = (bool)sender;

    if (!focus)
    {
        Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            // _ma is the MainActivity
            Toast.MakeText(_ma, Resource.String.camerafocusfailed, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        });
    }
}
```

I've try with a Nexus 5, this code works good. But with a Sony Xperia Z3 compact, there is always an error `camerafocusfailed`

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure how can you cast sender to bool... you can try to find out if camera supports autofocus.

```
var autoFocus = PackageManager.HasSystemFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus");
```

Comment: On the Nexus 5, my code works, I've try to focus on a very close surface and the focus failed. With a "normal" distance it works. With the Z3 compact, it failed. The preview is changing (trying to focus) but always fail.